Background Image too far zoomed in on physical iPad
I cant seem to figure this out. I am using Next.js, typescript, and chakraUi.

When viewing my application through inspect tools, it works exactly as envisioned.
When viewing my application through mobile it works as envisioned.
But when viewing on my physical iPad instead inspect tools, it is all the way zoomed in.
I could fix this by getting rid of 'fixed' in my desktop media query, but I want to keep fixed for desktop
I have tried many things including a scoping amount of recommendations from chatgpt, but cannot solve this issue.
Note: I have tried the chakraUI attributes such as base, md, sm, lg, but was not able to get that to work which is why I resorted to classic css styled max and min for media screen.

Is this a chakra specific issue?
< Container 
  maxW="100%"
  id="contact"
  backgroundImage={`url('/imgs/contact_banner.png')`}
  backgroundSize="cover" 
  sx={{
    backgroundAttachment: 'scroll', 
    
    // Media Queries
    '@media screen and (min-width: 390px)': {
      backgroundAttachment: 'scroll',  
    },
    '@media screen and (min-width: 481 and max-width: 768px)': {
      backgroundAttachment: 'scroll',  
      backgroundPosition: 'cover', 
    },
    '@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)': {
      backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',   
      backgroundSize: 'cover',         
      // backgroundPosition: 'center',    
    },
  }}
>


iOS Safari struggles with background-attachment fixed.

Could you use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being created? I’ve never heard of background-position cover for example.

Ive read that IO safari struggles with background fixed, but what confuses me is that why is that once I set media queries as scroll for mobile, it works fine on ios safari, but then an ipad wouldnt.

An iPad in landscape mode has a width of 1024px - and that's where you bring in fixed. Is that the difference?

< Container
  maxW="100%"
  id="contact"
  backgroundImage={`url('/imgs/contact_banner.png')`}
  sx={{
    backgroundAttachment: 'scroll', 
  
    '@media screen and (min-width: 390px)': {
      backgroundAttachment: 'scroll',

 
    },
    '@media screen and (min-width: 768px)': {
      backgroundAttachment: 'scroll', 

    },
    '@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)': {
      backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
      backgroundSize: '100% auto', 

    },
  }}

I had to get rid of the cover value above the sx={} and then adjust inside media queries. this solved it.

This is the correct syntax for combining min-width and max-width using "and".
Let me know if this doesn't fix the issue.
    '@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)': {
      backgroundAttachment: 'scroll',  
      backgroundSize: 'cover', 
    },
    


it does not unfortuantely
